# SASS/ SCSS custom css sheets for @import

Tags: css, ruby, compass-sass, sass

All I need is to do is have a directory with my custom reset sheets and other sass files for imports.

I've been playing around and I can't get compass to read my custom sheets.

1) Where do I put my custom css sheets for import? 
2) how do I @import them

(I'm using the sass indentation, but I doubt that makes a difference,)
(I know little about ruby I'm just using it for compass)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [@import section in Sass reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import).

You can import a Sass file without telling explicitly the file extension:

```
@import "file"; /*will import file.scss or file.sass. Anyway you could as well use @import "file.scss" or @import "file.sass*/
```

To import a CSS, provide its extension.

```
@import "file.css"; /*will import file.css"
```

There are more ways to differentiate them in the reference, but these are the most used.

You can put your files where you want, but write the path relative to the current directory (the directory which the file from where you are importing is).

Comment: I managed to solved my problem initially though you just confirmed a few things lingering in my head. Thanks for your help